# Get images from multiple folders within /images and place each folders contents in its own div

Tags: php, html, foreach, gallery, auto-populate

I am trying to make php do the following.

I have a structure of folders in my root directory. /images/1234, /images/2345, /images/3456 etc. (multiple folders all in images)

I would like to get the contents of each folder and put their contents into their own div, using php and not hard coding as the folders and files will change regularly.

```
<div><img src="images/1234/1.jpg"><img src="images/1234/2.jpg"><img src="images/1234/3.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="images/2345/1.jpg"><img src="images/2345/2.jpg"><img src="images/2345/3.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="images/3456/1.jpg"><img src="images/3456/2.jpg"><img src="images/3456/3.jpg"></div>
```

The files/folders will constantly be added so these divs would have to be in some sort of foreach loop for each folder found in the images directory.

Essentially each folder in images folder would be a div, the divs would auto populate as the browser was refreshed if new folder existed.

I can make it work with php to bring out all images and just place on page,r but I need this structure instead. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show us what you have done with php, so we can help you to improve your code.

Comment: I have been using many different existing php methods described here. I was trying to use,    $result = array();
$dir    = 'images/';

foreach(glob($dir.'*.jpg') as $filename) {
    $result[] = "<div"><img src=\"$filename\"></div>";
}   That just gets me individual images to each div. I tried to manipulate that a bit to no avail. I am a php noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (glob('images/*') as $dir) {
  echo '<div>'; // One div per directory
  foreach (glob($dir."/*.jpg") as $img) {
    echo "<img src='$img'/>";
  }
  echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need stored in one place all of your data structures in string format. example (sql database).
Then execute a sql query to retrieve all the locations of roads image files.
Then wrap with a php function in order to apply the paths (path).

This should be something like his.

**WITH SQL DATABASE**

```
<?php
// Formulate Query
$querySQL = "SELECT imageURL FROM tableImage";

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($querySQL );

//Gets all channels url images in an array variable
//Then attributed to code html image tag

<div><img src=".$result[0]." ></div>
<div><img src=".$result[1]." ></div>
<div><img src=".$result[2]." ></div>

?>
```

**WITHOUT SQL**
it is possible to do to retrieve the list of image files with their full path without sql. Only the folder path should be known and given hard.

```
<?php
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

<div><img src="$directory.$images[0]." ></div>
<div><img src="$directory.$images[1]." ></div>
<div><img src="$directory.$images[2]." ></div>

?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without sql. Essentially this is going to be a local site that will be hosted via my home network. Files are going to be stored and created via a workflow that brings in images from my camera. The files will then be stored in there respective folders and displayed in a div on webpage.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do to retrieve the list of image files with their full path. Only the folder path should be known and given hard.
I added an example above (To test! Should work without problem)

Comment: Ok I think this is going to work for me. Can I call all of those imgs in one div ie. <div><img src="$directory.$images[0]." ><img src="$directory.$images[1]." ><img src="$directory.$images[2]." ></div>  and then have multiple directories hardcoded ie $directory1, $directory2 etc. and call a foreach loop for each directory variable